# How to center this entire site with the container div

Tags: html, alignment, centering

I'm trying to help a person who created their own website (sort of, I'm not sure how much she's done on her own) but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

It's a simple change. She has a container div, then a header, left-side menu, right-side main content, and footer.

All I want to do is **force the entire site into the center**.

The CSS is:

```
#header {
width:900px;
}

#menu {
    float: left;
    width:154px;
    border-right: 1px solid grey; 
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width:730px;
    padding:2px;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    width:900px; 
}

#container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The site is: [here](http://www.eastsidetraders.com.au)

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The width of `body` is set to `740px`, change it to `100%` and the website will come in center. So add the following style:

```
body{
width: 100%;
}
```

See the screenshot:

[image]

But to be truly responsive you must give width of various container, header etc in % instead of fixed widths.

Answer (score 0):

Put `margin: 0 auto;` in the body.

Answer (score 0):

First off all place CSS-Reset in your code.